# How should I review one-line answers marked as low-quality

Tags: discussion

I just unlocked the ability to review low-quality posts, and I come across answers like these in reviewing quite frequently:

> I had a similar problem. Uninstalling the sonic wall vpn worked for me.
>
> (https://superuser.com/a/654063/201262)

In cases like these, should I simply comment and say "expound on that, one-line answers aren't very helpful"? What if there really isn't much more to say, like in this case?

But more importantly, should I mark these for **deletion** (of course, please explain *why*), **skip** them, or **approve them and ask for more** from the answerer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post itself really isn't great, but then again there's not much I can imagine that needs to go along with the solution. If uninstalling the software helps, so be it. In such a case I'd say the proper course of action would be to edit the post—the least you could do here is to properly capitalize "SonicWALL VPN"—and possibly up vote it, because it seems useful.

Note that the *low quality* algorithm finds quite a few posts that have useful content and simply need to be copyedited. The only low quality posts that should be marked for deletion are those that are unsalvageable through editing (or do not answer the question at all).

With the specific post you linked to, it's a little redundant though since the solution was already mentioned by @Walkerneo in a comment to the OP's answer. I asked them to post a proper answer. The low quality post has been deleted now.